# ¿Cómo construir un JSON anidado a partir de consultas relacionadas en LARAVEL 9?

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel-9

podrían colaborarme con lo siguiente.
Estoy trabajando en una consulta en Laravel que me imprima los resultados que se encuentran en dos tablas de la siguiente manera.

```
[
  {
    "invoice_id": 5,    
    "total": "1620000.00",
    "status": "open",
    "businessName": "Mauricio Jose Tovar Iglesias",
    "firstName": "Mauricio",
    "secondName": "Jose",
    "surname": "Tovar",
    "paymentReceivedItem": []
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": 4,    
    "total": "1800000.00",
    "status": "cloced",
    "businessName": "Cuantias menores",
    "firstName": "Cuantias",
    "secondName": null,
    "surname": "Menores",
    "paymentReceivedItem": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "payment": 3,
        "amount": null,
        "invoice": 4,
        "paymentOfMethod": "CASH",
        "paid": "1800000.00",
        "bank": 5,
        "status": "cloced"     
      },
       {
        "id": 4,
        "payment": 4,
        "amount": null,
        "invoice": 4,
        "paymentOfMethod": "CASH",
        "paid": "1800000.00",
        "bank": 5,
        "status": "cloced"     
      }
    ]
 ]
```

Se obtienen un listado de Ventas y los pagos que se le aplican a dichas ventas, lo que hago actualmente es primero consultar la tabla ventas

```
$sale = Sale::all();
```

y luego recorrer cada venta y asignarle los datos de la tabla pagos de la siguiente forma.

```
    $x=0;
    foreach ( $sale as $element){        
    $paymentReceivedItem = Payment::where('invoice' , '=' , $element->invoice_id)->get();
    $sale[$x]->paymentReceivedItem = $paymentReceivedItem;
    $x++;        
    }
```

Esto actualmente resuelve mi problema, el asunto es que quisiera mejorar esta versión de mi código para de esta forma optimizar mis resultados ya que esta es la mas sencilla, hay otras donde se obtienen mas nodos anidados y se pueden imaginar.
De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esperas obtener no es un JSON. Es un objeto (en php sería un array asociativo). Sólo se convertiría en un json al momento de entregarlo como respuesta en uno de tus api endpoints. Ahí el objeto se serializa a un string con Javascript Object Notation, o sea JSON.

Dicho esto, para lo que necesitas tendrías que declarar la relación en un método del modelo Sale

```
public function payments(): HasMany {
   return $this->hasMany(Payment::class,'invoice');
}
```

(el segundo parámetro `invoice` es necesario porque la llave foránea en el modelo `Payment` no se llama como Laravel esperaría, `sale_id`)

Y luego traerías los pagos con un eager load:

```
$sale = Sale::with(['payments'])->all();
```

Comment: Mi estimado muchas gracias justo lo que necesitaba,  había escuchado de el eager load pero no sabia como aplicarlo... 